# how to remove default value in mui textfield so I can type new value without showing the default one?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to remove the default value which in my case is 0, I want to add different number to it yet totally remove the 0.

```js
const [valueTextField, SetTextField] = useState<number>(0);

  const rest = () => {
    SetTextField('');
  };

        <TextField
          label={'Time'}
          defaultValue={valueTextField}
          variant='standard'
          name='time'
          onChange={handleChange}
          onFocus={rest}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

in this way you can do that , but I don't prefer to use :

```
   import React, { Component ,useState} from "react";
import {useTheme ,TextField,Typography} from "@mui/material"

const App = () => {

    const [valueTextField, SetTextField] = useState(0);

    const rest = () => {
        SetTextField('');
    };
 const handleChange = () => {
    //
    };

    return (
        <>
            <TextField
                label={'Time'}
                defaultValue={valueTextField}
                variant='standard'
                value={valueTextField}
                name='time'
                onChange={(e)=>{
                    SetTextField(e.target.value);
                    console.log(valueTextField)
                    handleChange(e)}}
                onFocus={rest}
                InputProps={{onfocus:rest}}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use onFocus event to reset the default value in the text field.

```
onFocus={(e) => e.target.value = ""}
```